# Как правильно реализовать интерфейс ICloneable для коллекции SortedList<double, List<int>>

Tags: c#, коллекции, клонирование

Добрый день.
У меня возникла проблема с реализацией интерфейса ICloneable в коллекции.
Объявил два класса:

```
public class CloneableSortedList<TKey, TValue> : SortedList<TKey, TValue> where TValue : ICloneable
{
    public SortedList<TKey, TValue> Clone()
    {
        CloneableSortedList<TKey, TValue> clone = new CloneableSortedList<TKey, TValue>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> pair in this)
        {
            clone.Add(pair.Key, (TValue)pair.Value.Clone());
        }
        return clone;
    }
}
public class CloneableList<T> : List<T> where T : ICloneable
{
    public List<T> Clone()
    {
        CloneableList<T> clone = new CloneableList<T>();
        clone.AddRange(this);
        return clone;
    }
}
```

Но при объявлении `CloneableSortedList<double, List<int>> clonelist;` появляется ошибка:

> Тип "System.Collections.Generic.List" не может быть использован
>   как параметр типа "TValue" в универсальном типе или методе
>   "CloneableSortedList". Нет преобразования неявной ссылки
>   из "System.Collections.Generic.List" в "System.ICloneable".

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно объявить класс `CloneableSortedList`.

Comment: `CloneableSortedList<double, CloneableList<int>>`

Comment: Извиняюсь, то была моя опечатка. С CloneableSortedList<double, CloneableList<int>> Тип "Spreader.CloneableList<int>" не может быть использован как параметр типа "TValue" в универсальном типе или методе "CloneableSortedList<TKey, TValue>". Нет преобразования неявной ссылки из "Spreader.CloneableList<int>" в "System.ICloneable".

Comment: А, ну так объявите его чтобы был ICloneable

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, где еще необходимо объявить?

Comment: @handy: `public class CloneableList<T> : List<T>, ICloneable where T : ICloneable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class CloneableList<T> : List<T> where T : ICloneable
```

**Объяснение:** Вы тут говорите, что CloneableList наследует List, у которого T должен быть ICloneable. Но CloneableList не реализует интерфейс ICloneable(потому что вы его не указали в реализуемых. Сказали только, что T должен быть ICloneable).

**Решение:** Добавьте еще реализацию интерфейса ICloneable к этому классу.

P.S. Если что, гуглим "Явная и неявная реализация интерфейса."

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, получилось. Не подскажите как реализовать здесь же интерфейс ICompareable? Чтобы коллекция была отсортирована по убыванию ключа.

Comment: @handy не чурайтесь использовать документацию. Там частенько годные примеры
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx
Суть в том, чтобы ваш объект, коллекцию которых вы хотите отсортировать, реализовал этот интерфейс и в методе CompareTo рассказал все коллекциям, как конкретно его сортировать(по какому полю). Далее List.Sort() вызывается. Поищите, может если Sort по убывающей или еще как то. Обычно в CompareTo пишутся просто поля, по которым сортировать объект. Возможно понадобится компаратор https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.23.php